# Capture IO of spawned program in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, io, spawn

I'm writing a program in Java which relies on a pre-compiled third party JAR residing in the same directory as mine.  At runtime, my program checks if this file exists, then downloads it if it doesn't.  Its main class is then executed.  However, the spawned program prints a large amount of text directly to the console.  Is there any way to 'capture' (and therefore hide) this output from `stdout` and return my own input directly from my parent application to `stdin`?  I would ideally like the child program to reside inside the same JVM, so I would like to avoid any version of `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: When starting the JAR, can you pipe the output to a file or some other readable medium?

Comment: The pre-compiled JAR makes calls directly to variations of `System.out.print()`.  Since I cannot modify these calls, is there still any way to pipe this output?

Comment: Just use `System.setOut`

Comment: Do you do anything else (e.g. in a different thread) while the third-party code is executing? I'm wondering if you can use `System.setOut` - edit: beaten by 1 second :P

Comment: @robbie_c At the moment, I'm spawning the thid-party JAR as a new thread, but this is the only thread other than the parent one.  I would still like my parent thread to be able to print to and receive input from the console.  Is this possible if I have used `System.setOut`?

Comment: Instead of executing the Jar via a Process, simply use a URLClassloader and load the Jar into. Using that classloader, you would then need to load and instantiate the class. This may require some use of reflection

Comment: @MTCoster would this do? `foo = System.out; System.setOut(bar); launchThirdPartyCode(); foo.println("bla"); waitForThirdPartyCodeToFinish(); System.setOut(foo); System.out.println("bla");` and the output of the third party stream will be in `bar`

Comment: @robbie_c so any output to `System.out` from the third party code would be diverted to `bar`? If there's a similar way to do this for the input stream could you post the whole lot as an answer?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want your code to be able to read from stdin, and you want to be able to write stuff to the input of the third party code?

Comment: Yes, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java 1.5+ `ProcessBuilder` class and the `Process` class.  Remember that the process will block if you don't handle its streams correctly.

Comment: Will this not spawn it in a new JVM?  And how does this help me capture the IO stream?

Comment: You're right.  The advantage of Process is that it has getOutputStream and getInputStream methods.  Do you actually need to use the 3rd-part JAr's main method? Can you call its service without invoking its main? You'll still have the standard IO strem problems though.

Comment: No, I don't need to call the main class directly, but I would like to keep the whole thing inside a single JVM if at all possible.

Comment: I gues the best thing to do is just to call the main method as a regular method, not as an external application.  But first call System.setOut, using a piped stream, as the other commenters suggested.